# Geth & SOCKS5 Proxy

Tags: go-ethereum

I would like to run Geth in Mac with SOCKS5 Proxy, as my network's firewall seems blocking port 30303. I am using Proxifier to setup SOCKS5 Proxy.

The proxy is Internet-accessible, but the peer connections are timed out, as shown in the image. What did I miss? How do I use Geth with SOCKS5 Proxy?

p.s. I'm actually using Ethereum Wallet, but it's Geth underneath.

[image]